# Slow response time for site

Tags: linux

I'm using Apache + PHP with default config on CentOS 5.  I increased only prefork connections.  The server has over 10000 connections on port 80.  The server hosts mobile sites and all pages load ads from another server (with PHP curl).

My server config:
 - Intel e3 -1270 (2x4x3.4GHZ)
 - 16 gb ram
 - 2 tb hdd with raid10

Average load between 1 to 2

The main problem is when a site loads ads from another server then pages will take a long time to open.

I'm also using CSF firewall.  I have also tried nginx (frontend nginx, backend apache).

Comment: More information and details are needed to provide any useful answers. For example, does "10000 connections" mean per concurrent, per hour, per day, unique visitors, etc....? Output from top, vmstat, iostat, etc... may also be helpful.

Answer (score 5):

Including ads (or any other content) this way is bound to be slow. You might look into either separating out the ad serving into a separate page that can be requested via an AJAX call after the page is loaded, or let the third party ad provider host the ads directly to be included in an iframe, etc.

Comment: What Jake said.  Your webmaster-level architecture is fundamentally broken and slow (loading ads via a serial process and making your server do that work/chew up your bandwidth, as opposed to making the client's browser do it in parallel with everything else).  Address that before you start tearing apart your server looking for where the speed went.

Comment: sir , 1st thks for reply , im owner of mobile site , so publisher code in CURLOPT_PROXY . Sir when i restart httpd site working fast for 5-15 mins , after 15 mins it come slow .